# How does one process "select *" and "select count(*)" from same stored procedure using SqlCommand::Execute (or an alternative)?

Tags: c++, sqlcommand

A stored procedure that I have returns a result set following by a count(*). This is a Sybase stored procedure ported over to MS SQL 2012.

So for example, it does...

```
select @resn=resn from borrower_reservations where <conditions>
select count(*) from borrower_reservations where <conditions>
```

@resn is defined as an int out parameter.

I've been unable to figure out how one goes about obtain both results using SqlCommand::Execute() in C++.

I'm aware that ExecuteNonQuery() will populate out parameters and that ExecuteScalar() is best for single values including count(*).

ExecuteReader() doesn't seem to work since a HasRows test returns false.

Is it feasible to handle this type of stored procedure, or does the stored procedure have to be re-written?

Comment: The post appears to have been corrupted. It should read "select @resn=resn from borrower_reservations where conditions" and then "select count(*) from borrower_reservations where conditions" (ie: two separate statements, one after the other

Answer (score 0):

See [SqlDataReader.NextResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.nextresult.aspx) (an SqlDataReader is returned by [SqlCommand.ExecuteReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k.aspx)):

> Advances the data reader to the next result [set], when reading the results of batch Transact-SQL statements.